# How do I find why a python scripts runs in significantly different running times on different machines?

Tags: python, mysql, runtime

### The Facts:

1. I am working on a NoteBook with Intel Core 2 Duo 2,26 GHz and 4 Gigabyte of Ram.
   It has a Apache Server and a MySQL Server running.
2. My Server (I did `lshw | less`) shows a 64 Bit CPU with 2,65 GHz and 4 Gigabyte Ram, too. It has the XAMPP-Package running on it.
3. The Database structures (tables, indices, ...) are identical and so is the Python script I am running.

### The Problem:

While the script runs in approximately **30 seconds on my macbook** it took the script **11 minutes on the server**!

What are the points you would check first for a bottleneck?

### The Solution:

There were two indices missing on one of the machines. I added them and voilá: Everything was super! The `EXPLAIN' keyword of MySQL was worth a mint. =)

Comment: I would also check to see if anything else was running at the same time on the server.

Comment: @James: I don't know what processes are running on this machine. So I did a quick `htop`. This gave me that from 3782 MB available there is only 320 MB of free Ram. Could this be a bottleneck?

Comment: I'd suggest that it might. Run a `ps -e` and a `top -n 1` that should get you a bit more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of server? If you're renting a  VPS or similar you're contending with other users for CPU time.

What platform is running on both? Tell us more about your situation!

Comment: The Notebook I am using for work is a MacBook late 2009, so there is OS X Snow Leopard on it. The server has Ubuntu running on it and is not rented. It is a server standing somewhere at work. I never saw it. Is it possible to get information about the server by terminal? I have root rights.

Comment: if you run `top` you will get some idea of what's going on on the server. Also the load averages displayed by `uptime` will give you some idea. Finally, `who` will tell you who else is logged in. What is the server's purpose?

Comment: `htop` gave me, that there is only 300 MB of free memory. This could be the bottleneck, couldn't it? I am the only user working on this machine right now.

Comment: If you're running a big query, 300MB of ram could definitely be the issue. I'd have a word to the sysad, in all likelihood you'll say it's slow and he'll say "Of course because...."

Comment: Thank you for your hints! I'll try to get more ram or another server.

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the databases in question are of similar scope. You say they're the same structure, but are they sized similarly? If your test case only has 100 entries when production has 100000000, that's one huge potential area for performance problems.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but the databases had the same amount of entries.